# Raphael: onclick delay on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I'm using Raphael to create an interactive pie chart. Onclick on mobile seem to be laggy. What would be the appropriate way to change the below to a "touch" based solution that isn't so slow?

I also noticed that in IE11 that the function myHoverOut isn't activating. I'm not entirely sure why. Works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.onload = function () {


          var w = 330;
          var h = 330;
          var R = Raphael("paper");
          R.setViewBox(0,0,w,h,true);

          var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
          svg.removeAttribute("width");
          svg.removeAttribute("height");

          // Setting preserveAspectRatio to 'none' lets you stretch the SVG
          R.canvas.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');

          var iconStyle = {
              fill: "#fff",
              stroke: "",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };


          var segmentStyle = {
              fill: "#1b2833",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStylePeople = {
              fill: "#005190",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleMoney = {
              fill: "#0f5086",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleIP = {
              fill: "#0d4b7c",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleScience = {
              fill: "#0f4873",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleEndors = {
              fill: "#0f436a",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleLegislator = {
              fill: "#144162",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleChain = {
              fill: "#173c59",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStylevaluePrice = {
              fill: "#1d3853",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStylemarketNeed = {
              fill: "#20364b",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleAssets = {
              fill: "#223343",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };

          var segmentStyleLeadEnt = {
              fill: "#252d38",
              stroke: "#fff",
              "stroke-width": 1,
              "stroke-linejoin": "round",
              cursor: "pointer"
          };


          var wheel = {};
          wheel.people = R.path("M205.1,84.2c-0.8-0.4-1.6-0.7-2.5-1.1c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-5.4-2.2-11-3.9-16.6-5 c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-5.7-1.1-11.5-1.7-17.3-1.7h-0.5c-4.7,0-9.4,0.4-14,1.1l-4.7-6.5l-0.8-1.1v0l-40.8-57 c9.1-3.5,18.4-6.2,27.9-8.1c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c10.5-2.1,21.2-3.1,31.9-3.1h0.5c10.7,0,21.4,1.1,31.9,3.1 c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.1c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1,0.2l3.6,72v0l0.1,1.2v0L205.1,84.2z").attr(segmentStylePeople);
          wheel.leadEntrepreneur = R.path("M285,50l-0.3,0.6l-35.6,62l-0.6,1l-3.3,5.8c-0.5-0.8-1-1.7-1.6-2.5c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4 c-3.2-4.7-6.9-9.2-11-13.4c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3c-4.2-4.1-8.7-7.8-13.4-11c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3 c-4.1-2.7-8.5-5.1-12.9-7.1l-0.3-6.2v0l-0.1-1.2v0l-3.6-72c10.1,2.1,20.1,5.1,29.7,9.1c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2 c9.8,4.1,19.3,9.1,28.3,15.1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c8.7,5.9,17,12.7,24.8,20.4C284.8,49.8,284.9,49.9,285,50L285,50z").attr(segmentStyleLeadEnt);
          wheel.assets = R.path("M330.4,134.2l-1.8,0.9l0,0l-1.7,0.8l0,0l-60.1,31.2l-1,0.5l-7,3.6c0-1.2,0.1-2.4,0.1-3.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5 c0-5.8-0.6-11.6-1.7-17.3c0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5c-1.1-5.7-2.8-11.2-5.1-16.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-1.8-4.4-4-8.7-6.6-12.8l3.3-5.8 l0.6-1l35.6-62L285,50c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c7.7,7.7,14.5,16,20.4,24.8c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4c6,9,11.1,18.5,15.1,28.3 c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5C325.2,113.9,328.3,124,330.4,134.2").attr(segmentStyleAssets);
          wheel.marketNeed = R.path("M333.7,167.2v0.5c0,10.7-1,21.4-3.1,31.9c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5c-2,9.9-4.8,19.6-8.6,29l-6.3-0.6h0l-1.8-0.2h0 l-63.6-5.9l-1.1-0.1l-7.9-0.7c0.7-1,1.5-2.1,2.2-3.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c3.3-4.9,6-10,8.2-15.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5 c2.3-5.4,3.9-11,5-16.7c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.5c0.9-4.5,1.4-9.1,1.6-13.7l7-3.6l1-0.5l60.1-31.2l0,0l1.7-0.8l0,0l1.8-0.9 c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5C332.7,145.8,333.7,156.5,333.7,167.2").attr(segmentStylemarketNeed);
          wheel.valuePrice = R.path("M322,229.2c-0.2,0.6-0.5,1.2-0.7,1.7c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5c-4.1,9.8-9.1,19.3-15.1,28.3 c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4v0c-5.9,8.8-12.7,17-20.4,24.8c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1 c-6.7,6.7-13.9,12.8-21.4,18.1l-10.3-8.1h0l-1.3-1.1l0,0l-46.7-36.5l-0.8-0.7l-4.8-3.8c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.7,2.8-1.1 c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2c5.3-2.2,10.5-4.9,15.4-8.2c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c4.7-3.2,9.3-6.9,13.4-11.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1 c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c3.2-3.3,6.2-6.8,8.9-10.4l7.9,0.7l1.1,0.1l63.6,5.9h0l1.8,0.2h0L322,229.2z").attr(segmentStylevaluePrice);
          wheel.supplyChain = R.path("M263.5,303.5c-1.1,0.8-2.2,1.6-3.4,2.3c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.3c-9,6-18.5,11.1-28.3,15.2 c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2c-10,4.1-20.3,7.2-30.7,9.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1c-8.1,1.6-16.3,2.6-24.5,3l-7.5-21.4l-0.5-1.5 l-17.8-51.1l-0.4-1l-0.6-1.7c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.1c5.7,1.1,11.5,1.7,17.3,1.7h0.5 c5.8,0,11.6-0.6,17.3-1.7h0c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c4.7-1,9.3-2.3,13.9-4l4.8,3.8l0.9,0.7l46.7,36.5l0,0l1.3,1.1h0L263.5,303.5z").attr(segmentStyleChain);
          wheel.legislatorsRegulators = R.path("M175.1,333.8c-2.5,0.1-5,0.2-7.5,0.2h-0.5c-10.7,0-21.4-1.1-32-3.1c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1 c-10.5-2.1-20.7-5.2-30.7-9.3c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-6.2-2.6-12.3-5.5-18.2-8.9l8-33.3l0.4-1.5l10.5-43.8c3.8,3.7,7.9,7,12.2,9.8 c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c4.9,3.3,10,6,15.4,8.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c5.1,2.1,10.4,3.7,15.8,4.9l0.6,1.7l0.4,1l17.8,51.1 l0.5,1.5L175.1,333.8z").attr(segmentStyleLegislator);
          wheel.independantEndorsement = R.path("M104.1,233.7l-10.5,43.8l-0.4,1.5l-8,33.3c-3.4-2-6.8-4-10.1-6.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3 c-8.8-5.9-17.1-12.7-24.8-20.4l-0.4-0.4c-7.7-7.7-14.5-16-20.4-24.8c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4c-2.8-4.3-5.5-8.6-7.9-13.1l33.4-32 l1.1-1l23.5-22.5c1,3.8,2.3,7.5,3.8,11.2c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c2.2,5.3,5,10.5,8.2,15.4c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4 c3.2,4.7,6.9,9.3,11.1,13.5c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3l0.1,0.1C103.2,232.9,103.6,233.3,104.1,233.7").attr(segmentStyleEndors);
          wheel.underpinningScience = R.path("M77.7,185.6c0.4,1.8,0.8,3.6,1.3,5.4l-23.5,22.5l-1.1,1l-33.4,32c-2.7-5-5.1-10-7.2-15.2 c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-4.1-10-7.2-20.3-9.3-30.7c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5C2,189.1,1,178.4,1,167.8v-0.5 c0-3.5,0.1-6.9,0.4-10.4l55.9-10.9h0l1.4-0.3h0l21-4.1c-0.8,2.6-1.4,5.2-2,7.9c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5c-1.1,5.7-1.7,11.5-1.7,17.3 v0.5c0,5.8,0.6,11.6,1.7,17.3C77.6,185.3,77.6,185.4,77.7,185.6").attr(segmentStyleScience);
          wheel.intellectualProperty = R.path("M106.7,99.2c-1.3,1.1-2.5,2.3-3.7,3.5l-0.4,0.4c-4.2,4.2-7.9,8.7-11,13.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4 c-3.3,4.9-6,10-8.2,15.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5c-1.2,2.9-2.2,5.8-3.1,8.8l-21,4.1h0l-1.4,0.3h0L1.4,156.8 c0.5-7.2,1.4-14.4,2.8-21.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5c2.1-10.5,5.2-20.7,9.3-30.7c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5c4.1-9.8,9.1-19.2,15.1-28.3 c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c1.2-1.7,2.4-3.4,3.6-5.1l60.6,24.1l1.3,0.5L106.7,99.2z").attr(segmentStyleIP);
          wheel.money = R.path("M148.4,70.7l-0.8-1.1v0l-40.8-57c-0.9,0.4-1.9,0.7-2.8,1.1v0c-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2 c-9.8,4.1-19.3,9.1-28.3,15.1c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.3C66,35.2,57.7,42,50,49.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3l-0.1,0.1 c-6.2,6.2-11.8,12.8-16.8,19.7l60.6,24.1l1.3,0.5l12,4.8c3.1-2.8,6.3-5.2,9.7-7.5c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c4.9-3.3,10-6,15.4-8.2 c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2c5.4-2.2,11-3.9,16.6-5c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.2-0.4,3.3-0.6L148.4,70.7z").attr(segmentStyleMoney);

          var icon = {};
          icon.people = R.path("M178.1,40.9l0-1.2c1.7,0.2,5.1-1,5.1-1c-1.2-1.2-1.4-2.6-2.2-8s-5.5-5.4-5.8-5.4c-0.4,0-5.1-0.1-5.8,5.4 c-0.8,5.4-1,6.8-2.2,8c0,0,3.4,1.2,5.1,1l0,1.2c-0.9,0.9-1.9,1.7-2.9,2.3c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,1,0.5c2.3,1.2,4.4,2.4,4.4,4.8v2.6h10.6 c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7v-3C186,44.7,181,44.1,178.1,40.9 M164.8,41.2L164.8,41.2v-1c0.9-1,1.5-2.2,2-3.5c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.5-0.2,0.8-0.8,0.9-1.6 c0-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.4-0.9c0-0.7,0-1.5,0-2.3c0-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.1-1.9c0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5 c-0.7-3.9-4.2-4.3-5.5-4.3c-0.1,0-1,0-1,0c-1.3,0-4.9,0.4-5.5,4.3c0,0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.5c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.3-0.1,1.9 c0,0.8,0,1.6,0,2.3c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.9c0,0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7c0.1,0.8,0.5,1.4,0.9,1.6c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.4,1.2 c0.4,1.1,1,2.1,1.8,3v1c-3.3,3.6-8.8,4.3-8.8,7.3v3.3c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7h23.4c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7v-3.3 C173.6,45.5,168.1,44.8,164.8,41.2").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.leadEntrepreneur = R.path("M237.7,43.1c9.4,0,17,7.6,17,17c0,3.7-1.2,7.1-3.2,9.9c-0.2-3.5-2-4.8-2-4.8c-0.7-1.7-5.3-3.1-5.3-3.1 c-1.7-0.6-2.2-1.2-2.4-1.5c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1v0c0,0,0,0,0-0.1v0c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.8-0.2-1c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.5c0,0,0,0,0,0 c0.6-0.7,1-1.5,1.3-2.4c0.5-0.5,0.8-1.8,0.8-1.8c0.3-1,0.2-1.5,0.1-1.7c0-0.1,0.9-2.7-0.3-4.7c0,0-0.4-1.9-2.6-2.7 c-2-1.2-5-0.5-5-0.5c-3.7,0.6-4.5,4.9-4.5,4.9c-0.2,2,0.3,3.2,0.3,3.3c-0.2,0.5,0.2,1.7,0.2,1.7c0.1,0.7,0.5,1,0.6,1 c0.3,0.9,0.7,1.8,1.3,2.6c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0.3,0,0.7c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0,0.2-0.2,0.8-0.2,0.9c0,0,0,0,0,0 c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c-1.4,1.1-4.7,2.1-4.7,2.1c-1.4,0.6-2,1.4-2,1.4c-1.5,2.2-2.1,4.4-2.3,5.5c-2.1-2.8-3.3-6.3-3.3-10 C220.7,50.7,228.3,43.1,237.7,43.1 M237.7,41.5c-10.3,0-18.6,8.3-18.6,18.6c0,10.3,8.3,18.6,18.6,18.6c10.3,0,18.6-8.3,18.6-18.6 C256.3,49.9,248,41.5,237.7,41.5").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.assets = R.path("M286.8,125.6c-3.4,0-6.2-2.8-6.2-6.2c0-3.4,2.8-6.2,6.2-6.2c3.4,0,6.2,2.8,6.2,6.2 C293,122.8,290.2,125.6,286.8,125.6 M304.9,117.1c-0.1-0.5-0.6-1-1.1-1l-2.3-0.1c-0.5,0-1.1-0.5-1.2-0.9l-0.8-2.1 c-0.2-0.5-0.1-1.2,0.2-1.5l1.5-1.7c0.3-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-3.3-3.3c-0.4-0.3-1-0.3-1.4,0l-1.7,1.5c-0.4,0.3-1.1,0.4-1.5,0.2l-2.1-0.8 c-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.7-0.9-1.2l-0.1-2.3c0-0.5-0.5-1-1-1.1c0,0-1.2-0.2-2.3-0.2c-1.1,0-2.3,0.2-2.3,0.2c-0.5,0.1-1,0.6-1,1.1l-0.1,2.3 c0,0.5-0.5,1.1-0.9,1.2l-2.1,0.8c-0.5,0.2-1.2,0.1-1.5-0.2l-1.7-1.5c-0.4-0.3-1-0.4-1.4,0l-3.3,3.3c-0.3,0.4-0.3,1,0,1.4l1.5,1.7 c0.3,0.4,0.4,1.1,0.2,1.5l-0.8,2.1c-0.2,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.9l-2.3,0.1c-0.5,0-1,0.5-1.1,1c0,0-0.2,1.2-0.2,2.3s0.2,2.3,0.2,2.3 c0.1,0.5,0.6,1,1.1,1l2.3,0.1c0.5,0,1.1,0.5,1.2,0.9l0.8,2.1c0.2,0.5,0.1,1.2-0.2,1.5l-1.5,1.7c-0.3,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l3.3,3.3 c0.4,0.3,1,0.3,1.4,0l1.7-1.5c0.4-0.3,1.1-0.4,1.5-0.2l2.1,0.8c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.7,0.9,1.2l0.1,2.3c0,0.5,0.5,1,1,1.1 c0,0,1.2,0.2,2.3,0.2c1.1,0,2.3-0.2,2.3-0.2c0.5-0.1,1-0.6,1-1.1l0.1-2.3c0-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.9-1.2l2.1-0.8c0.5-0.2,1.2-0.1,1.5,0.2 l1.7,1.5c0.4,0.3,1,0.4,1.4,0l3.3-3.3c0.3-0.4,0.3-1,0-1.4l-1.5-1.7c-0.3-0.4-0.4-1.1-0.2-1.5l0.8-2.1c0.2-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.9 l2.3-0.1c0.5,0,1-0.5,1.1-1c0,0,0.2-1.2,0.2-2.3S304.9,117.1,304.9,117.1").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.marketNeed = R.path("M312.6,187.5c-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.5-1.1-0.5h-9.2c-0.6-4-3-9.8-9-9.8s-8.4,5.8-9,9.8h-9.1c-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.1,0.5 c-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.8-0.2,1.2l6.1,18.5c0.2,0.6,0.7,0.8,1.3,0.8h24.1c0.6,0,1.1-0.3,1.3-0.8l6.1-18.6 C313,188.2,312.9,187.8,312.6,187.5z M303,195h4.8l-1.6,5H303V195z M278.9,195h5.1v5h-3.5L278.9,195z M293,190v4h-8v-4H293z M293,195v5h-8v-5H293z M285,201h8v4h-8V201z M294,201h7v4h-7V201z M294,200v-5h7v5H294z M294,194v-4h7v4H294z M293.3,180 c4.3,0,5.7,4,6.2,7h-12.4C287.6,184,289,180,293.3,180z M284,190v4h-5.6l-1.3-4H284z M280.9,201h3.1v4h-1.7L280.9,201z M304.4,205 H303v-4h2.7L304.4,205z M308.2,194H303v-4h6.6L308.2,194z").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.valuePrice = R.path("M271.8,251v12.3h-4.2L271.8,251z M273.3,251l4.2,12.3h-4.2V251z M250.1,263.3V251l4.2,12.3H250.1z M248.6,251 v12.3h-4.2L248.6,251z M273.7,247.7h0.3c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1c0-0.6-0.5-1.1-1.1-1.1h-11.9l-0.1-4c0-0.6-0.5-1.1-1.1-1.1 c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1l-0.1,4h-11.9c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h0.3l-5.4,15.6c0,0,0,3.6,6.5,3.6 s6.5-3.6,6.5-3.6l-5.4-15.6h9.2l0,0.8c-0.6,0.4-0.9,1-0.9,1.8c0,0.7,0.3,1.3,0.8,1.7l-0.4,17.9c-6.9,0.5-6.9,3.6-6.9,3.6h17.4 c0,0,0-3.1-6.9-3.6l-0.4-17.9c0.5-0.4,0.8-1,0.8-1.7c0-0.7-0.4-1.4-0.9-1.8l0-0.8h9.2l-5.4,15.6c0,0,0,3.6,6.5,3.6 c6.5,0,6.5-3.6,6.5-3.6L273.7,247.7z").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.supplyChain = R.path("M187.5,290.5l-6.4,6.4h4.3v5.4c0,0.8,0.3,1.7,0.9,2.3c0.6,0.6,1.5,0.9,2.3,0.9h19.3c0.8,0,1.7-0.3,2.3-0.9 c0.6-0.6,0.9-1.5,0.9-2.3v-5.4h-4.3v4.3h-17.2v-4.3h4.3L187.5,290.5L187.5,290.5z M188.6,279.8c-0.8,0-1.7,0.3-2.3,0.9 c-0.6,0.6-0.9,1.5-0.9,2.3v5.4h4.3v-4.3h17.1v4.3h-4.3l6.4,6.4l6.4-6.4h-4.3V283c0-0.8-0.3-1.7-0.9-2.3c-0.6-0.6-1.5-0.9-2.3-0.9 H188.6L188.6,279.8z").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.legislatorsRegulators = R.path("M132.2,300.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3v1.9c0,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.9,0.9h-19.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-24.9 c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9H131c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v7.2l2.8-3.5v-4.5c0-1.7-1.4-3.1-3.1-3.1H111c-1.7,0-3.1,1.4-3.1,3.1v26.4 c0,1.7,1.4,3.1,3.1,3.1h20.6c1.7,0,3.1-1.4,3.1-3.1v-6.1L132.2,300.3z M128.3,299.7c-0.7,0-1.4-0.3-1.9-0.9l-4.6-5.3c-0.9-1-0.8-2.6,0.3-3.5c1-0.9,2.6-0.8,3.5,0.3l2.6,3l9.5-12 c0.8-1.1,2.4-1.2,3.5-0.4c1.1,0.8,1.2,2.4,0.4,3.5l-11.4,14.3C129.8,299.3,129.1,299.6,128.3,299.7L128.3,299.7z").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.independantEndorsement = R.path("M74.1,246l-4.5-0.7l-2.4-3.9c-0.5-0.8-1.2-0.8-1.7,0l-2.6,3.9l-4.3,0.5c-0.9,0.1-1.2,0.8-0.7,1.6l2.7,4.4 l-0.5,4.5c-0.1,0.9,0.5,1.4,1.3,1.1l4.9-1.6l4.8,1.7c0.8,0.3,1.4-0.2,1.4-1.1l-0.4-4.6l2.9-4.3C75.3,246.8,75,246.1,74.1,246 M66.3,266c-3.4,0-6.6-1.1-9.3-2.9l-6,0.7c-1,0.1-1.6-0.6-1.3-1.5l1.8-5.6c-1-2.2-1.6-4.6-1.6-7.2c0-9.1,7.3-16.4,16.4-16.4 s16.4,7.3,16.4,16.4S75.4,266,66.3,266").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.underpinningScience = R.path("M54.2,178.3c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1s0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1S54.9,178.3,54.2,178.3 M44,188.6 c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1s0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1S44.6,188.6,44,188.6 M32.1,186.9c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1 c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1C33.2,186.4,32.7,186.9,32.1,186.9 M24.4,194.8c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1 c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1C25.5,194.3,25,194.8,24.4,194.8 M54.2,173.7c-1.9,0-3.5,1.6-3.5,3.5 c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.8l-5.5,5.5c-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.4-1.7-0.4c-1.4,0-2.6,0.8-3.2,2l-5.4-1c-0.4-1.5-1.7-2.7-3.4-2.7 c-1.9,0-3.5,1.6-3.5,3.5c0,0.6,0.1,1.1,0.4,1.6l-3.2,3.2c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.5-0.3c-1.9,0-3.5,1.6-3.5,3.5c0,1.9,1.6,3.5,3.5,3.5 c1.9,0,3.5-1.6,3.5-3.5c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.3-1.5l3.2-3.2c0.4,0.2,0.9,0.3,1.3,0.3c1.3,0,2.5-0.8,3.1-1.9l5.5,1.1 c0.4,1.5,1.8,2.5,3.3,2.5c1.9,0,3.5-1.6,3.5-3.5c0-0.4-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.3l5.8-5.8c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.2c1.9,0,3.5-1.6,3.5-3.5 C57.7,175.2,56.2,173.7,54.2,173.7").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.intellectualProperty = R.path("M45.4,132c0.7,1.3,2.1,2.2,3.7,2.2s3-0.9,3.7-2.2H45.4z M53.2,125c0.7,0,1.5-0.7,1.5-1.5c0-6.3,5.5-7.1,5.5-15.1c0-6.1-5-11.1-11.1-11.1c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1 c0,8,5.5,8.9,5.5,15.1c0,0.7,0.7,1.5,1.5,1.5H53.2z M54,127c0,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.9,0.9h-7.8c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9H53 C53.5,126.1,54,126.5,54,127 M54,130c0,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.9,0.9h-7.8c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9H53 C53.5,129.1,54,129.5,54,130").attr(iconStyle);
          icon.money = R.path("M92.2,50.1c-2-3-4-5-1.3-5.5c0.4-0.1,2.2-0.3,2.7-0.2c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.6c0.7,0.3,1.5,0.3,2.2,0.4 c0.8,0,1.7-0.2,2.4-0.4c0.5-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.6-0.6c0.6-0.1,2.2,0.3,2.5,0.3c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1,0.6c0.2,0.6-0.3,1.4-0.6,1.8 c-0.6,1-1.3,1.9-2,2.9l-0.8,1.1H93L92.2,50.1z M101.4,71.9h-8.2v-1.3l0.1-0.1c1.2-0.6,2-1.8,2-3.1c0-0.3,0-0.7-0.1-1.1h-1.9v-1.7H95 c-0.1-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.2-1.8c0-2.3,1.6-3.9,3.8-3.9c1.2,0,1.9,0.3,2.2,0.5l0.1,0.1l-0.5,1.7l-0.3-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.7-0.4-1.6-0.4 c-1.5,0-1.8,1.1-1.8,2.1c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.7h2.7v1.7h-2.5c0,0.7,0,1.3-0.1,1.9c-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.2-1,1.7h5.2V71.9z M112.1,67 c-2.2-5.1-6.2-10.7-10.5-13.4h-8.7c-4.2,2.7-8.2,8.3-10.5,13.4c-2.2,5.1,0.4,10.2,5.5,10.2h18.6C111.6,77.2,114.3,72.2,112.1,67").attr(iconStyle);


          var current = null;
          for (var segment in wheel) {

            (function (st, segment) {
                st[0].onmouseover = function () {
                    current && wheel[current].animate() && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
                    document.getElementById(segment).style.display = "block";
                    current = segment;
                };

                if (segment == "people") {
                    st[0].onmouseover();
                    wheel.people.animate({ fill: '#005190', transform: 's1.05' }, 200);
                    wheel.people.toFront();
                    icon.people.animate({ fill: '#FFFFFF', transform: 's1.2' }, 200);
                    icon.people.toFront();
                    var bounce = Raphael.animation({transform: 's1.2'}, 500, "bounce").repeat(Infinity);
                    icon.people.animate(bounce);
                    icon.people.toFront();
                }
            })(wheel[segment], segment);


            (function (st, segment) {

                st[0].onclick = function () {
                    current && wheel[current].animate() && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
                    document.getElementById(segment).style.display = "block";
                    current = segment;
                };

            })(wheel[segment], segment);


            wheel[segment].color = "#005190";
            wheel[segment].mouseover( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
            icon[segment].mouseover( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
            wheel[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
            icon[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )

            wheel[segment].mousedown( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
            icon[segment].mousedown( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
            wheel[segment].touchstart( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
            icon[segment].touchstart( myHover.bind(null, segment) )

            wheel[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
            icon[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
            wheel[segment].touchend( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
            icon[segment].touchend( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
          }
          function myHover( type ) {
            icon.people.stop();
            icon.people.animate({ fill: '#FFFFFF', transform: 's1' }, 200);
            wheel[ type ].animate({ fill: '#005190', transform: 's1.05' }, 200);
            icon[ type ].animate({ fill: '#FFFFFF', transform: 's1.2' }, 200);
            wheel[ type ].toFront();
            icon[ type ].toFront();
          }
          function myHoverOut( type ) {
            wheel[ type ].animate({ fill: '#1b2833', transform: 's1' }, 200);
            icon[ type ].animate({ fill: '#FFFFFF', transform: 's1' }, 200);
            icon.people.animate({ fill: '#FFFFFF', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.people.animate({ fill: '#005190', transform: 's1' }, 200);

                        wheel.leadEntrepreneur.animate({ fill: '#252d38', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.assets.animate({ fill: '#223343', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.marketNeed.animate({ fill: '#20364b', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.valuePrice.animate({ fill: '#1d3853', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.supplyChain.animate({ fill: '#173c59', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.legislatorsRegulators.animate({ fill: '#144162', transform: 's1' }, 200);

                        wheel.independantEndorsement.animate({ fill: '#0f436a', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.underpinningScience.animate({ fill: '#0f4873', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.intellectualProperty.animate({ fill: '#0d4b7c', transform: 's1' }, 200);
                        wheel.money.animate({ fill: '#0f5086', transform: 's1' }, 200);
          }
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: I can't give you a solution. But in my experience, it is the .animate() function that can/will cause the laggy soulution you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because you are making too many dom access. Try reducing the use of *document.getElementById* in the click function. You can achieve this by either of the following:

1. Use the 'this' keyword inside the onclick function.
2. Send the dom element as parameter to the click function when it is declared.

PS: I do not know your complete application so there can be other ways too to reduce dom interaction.

Comment: Full JS now added to message. Can you please give an example of what you are referencing?